# why I cannot activate elementor plug in?

Tags: plugins

I installed a theme and everything works fine, but once I activate the elementor plug in it shows the site cant be reached.

I did the troubleshoot , cleared browsing data , disabled the firewall , but none of these worked , I had another wordpress website and the elementor plug in was working fine, but in this site it not.
[image]

Comment: Your memory limit could be the issue here. Can you try adding this line to your `wp-config.php` file: `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );`

Comment: I have the file wp-config-sample, added the line still nothing happened

Comment: WordPress doesn't use the `wp-config-sample.php` file. You need `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Yes, but there is only the  **wp-config-sample.php**

Comment: Then that might be your problem. From the `wp-config.php` file WordPress gets its base configuration details (such as database info). If the file is missing, it's only logical nothing gets loaded in the front-end. I would advise you to duplicate your `wp-config-sample.php` file and rename it to `wp-config.php`. Then fill in your database information.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.